# @FindBy annotations cannot find the element, when element state is not visible

Tags: selenium, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity, findby

`@FindBy` annotation cannot find the element, when element state is not visible. We are writing some SEO tests those elements are not visible on webpage.

For example following is not working;

```
@CacheLookup
@FindBy(xpath = "//meta[@name='description']")
public WebElementFacade metaDescription;
```

But that works;

```
WebElement metaV2 = getDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//meta[@name='description']"));
```

It gives an error like;

```
org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Timed out after 15 seconds. Element not available
```

Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: what error u see while using findBy annotation ?

Comment: @CacheLookup is caching the result of your initial find and making sure that it doesn't try to find the element again.  This may be causing some unexpected side affects.

Comment: If you want to wait until something is visible the best option is to use an Explicit wait.

Comment: It doesn't work without @CacheLookup too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebElementFacade expects an element to be visible before interacting with it (as do many of the standard WebElement methods). If you want to check an invisible element, use a WebElement or avoid @FindBy entirely, e.g.

```
By META_V2 = By.xpath("//meta[@name='description']")
.
.
.
$(META_V2).shouldBePresent();
```